# Will there ever be blur effect on the launcher vertical bar?

Tags: unity

I have asked this multiple times before in other sites but no one seemed interested to answer me. When will the blur effect be implemented? I am guessing Canonical already has this in their list since it just doesn't look good when the launcher is over a white background, everything just gets too blurry. I'd just like to know when or this isn't going to be implemented at all?

Comment: Do you have a screenshot to help convey what you're looking for/at?

Comment: No one can answer your question because it's kind of hypothetical. We haven't had UDS yet for 11.10 so really it's anyone's guess what the plan is.

Comment: @Marco Ceppi. I don't want to sound rude but have you ever used Windows 7? Compare Unity's launcher to Win7's and you'll see.

Comment: @user13555 No I haven't, I haven't used a Microsoft Windows product in quite some time now. Not to sound equally rude, but to assume everyone has used Microsoft Windows products, let alone every Microsoft Windows Operating System is kind of silly.

Comment: I'll just add that in 13.10, the launcher is not blurred, but [the right-click menu's *are*](http://i.imgur.com/DUDrqEH.png)..